# How to use vapply to download web?

Tags: r

I can use lapply,sapply,mapply to download web.

```
urls <- c(
    "http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html",
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz")
x1=lapply(urls,readLines)
x2=sapply(urls,readLines)
x3=mapply(con=urls,readLines)
```

How to use vapply in this example?

Comment: You need to know the form of the output (`FUN.VALUE`), so in this case the number of lines that would be read (and this would have to be constant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to wrap `readLines` in something that will always return the same length vector

eg

```
vapply(urls, function(i)  list(readLines(i)), list(1))
```

This works because, while `readLines` will return a variable number of lines, it is the first element of a `list` of length 1

Comment: +1 nice “workaround“ for the “must be constant“ restriction of vapply()!